# Prove that ray CE intersects $\triangle ABC$ at a point $D$ on $AB$ and that $D$ must lie strictly between $A$ and $B$.

Tags: geometry

Let $CE$ be a ray that bisects $\angle ACB$ where $E$ is a point interior to the $\triangle ABC$. Prove that ray $CE$ intersects $\triangle ABC$ at a point $D$ on $AB$ and that $D$ must lies strictly between $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Your thoughts about the problem? Are you aware of the angle bisector theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)?

Comment: I think this question is to be understood as being at the very beginnings of axiomatic Euclidean geometry. I mean the modern version with Pasch's axiom or an equivalent. Euclid would never have worried about something like this. However, I'm curious about the condition that the ray "bisect" the angle. That assumption is not necessary.

Comment: I'm just confused on where to start with the proof. I know that an angle bisector means that the angle is directly cut in half. but how do i prove that it is strictly between A and B. It's obvious that it lies between it.

Comment: Allison, what kind of course are you taking? Does the fact that if you take two points on opposite sides of a line, the segment between those points must meet the line, figure prominently in what you're learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most situations, the given statement would be accepted as obvious. I'm not sure whether this is what Allison is looking for, but here is a proof based on the late 19th-early 20th century axiomatization of Euclidean geometry, especially the fact (equivalent to Pasch's Axiom) that every line divides the plane into two half-planes and whether a segment meets the line is determined by whether the endpoints of the segment are in the same or opposite half-planes.

The fact that $E$ is an interior point of $ABC$ means that:

(1) $E$ is on the same side of $BC$ as $A$;

(2) $E$ is on the same side of $AC$ as $B$; and

(3) $E$ is on the same side of $AB$ as $C$ (although we don't need this).

First we prove that $CE$ cannot be parallel to $AB$. Assume the contrary.

Note that $A$ and $B$ are on the same side of line $m = CE$. Denote by $H$ the half-plane to which they belong. Select a point  $F$ on line $CE$ but on the other side of $C$ from $E$. By (1), $F$ and $A$ are on opposite sides of $BC$ (since $E$ and $F$ are). Thus the segment $AF$ intersects line $CB$. But since segment $AF$ is situated in $H$, the point of intersection $G$ must in fact be on the ray $CB$. Since $G$ is between $A$ and $F$, points $F$ and $G$ are on the same side of line $AC$. But since $G$ is on ray $CB$, points $G$ and $B$ are also on the same side of $AC$. By transitivity, points $B$ and $F$ are on the same side of $AC$. By the definition of $F$, this shows that $E$ and $B$ are on opposite sides of $AC$, contradicting (2). Therefore $CE$ and $AB$ are not parallel.

It follows that line $CE$ intersects line $AB$ at some point $D$. We wish to prove that $D$ is between $A$ and $B$. We do this by eliminating the remaining possibilities. $D$ cannot coincide with $A$, because then $E$ would lie on the line $CA$, contradicting (2). Similarly, $D$ cannot be $B$. We will now show that $A$ cannot be between $B$ and $D$. Since it can be shown in the same way $B$ cannot be between $A$ and $D$, this is the last case to be addressed.

Assume therefore that $A$ is between $B$ and $D$. Thus $B$ and $D$ are on opposite sides of $CA$. By (2) therefore, $E$ and $D$ are on opposite sides of $CA$, hence of $C$. On the other hand, since $A$ and $D$ are on the same side of $B$, they're on the same side of $CB$. By (1) therefore $D$ and $E$ are on the same side of $CB$, hence of $C$. This is a contradiction.

From the foregoing we conclude that $D$ is between $A$ and $B$. It remains only to show that $D$ is on the *ray* $CE$. Since $D$ and $B$ are on the same side of $A$, they are on the same side of $CA$. Therefore, by (2), $E$ and $D$ are on the same side of $CA$, hence of $C$. Thus $D$ is on the ray $CE$.

Comment: I'm confused on to why we must prove that CE is not parallel to AB. Wouldn't we want to show it is not parallel to CB, since we are trying to prove that point D is between AB

Comment: You need to prove that: (1) the intersection $D$ of lines $CE$ and $AB$ *exists*; (2) $D$ is between $AB$; (3) $D$ is on the ray $CE$. Proving that $CE$ is not parallel to $AB$ is necessary in order to prove part (1). Depending on what theorems have already been proved at this stage, it might be shorter to use one of those.